# Can't center text in my h1 element in google chrome

Tags: http, text, centering

I'm having trouble centering my header in chrome. it works fine in JSfiddle but whenever I drop it into chrome, it doesn't center. I tried using margin: 0 auto for the block elements like  and  and align-text: center, but none of them are working. 
Here's my HTML and CSS

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container,
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-1-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.grid,
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/*
  ==============================
  Primary Header 
  ==============================
*/

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rysh</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container logo">
    <h1>Rysh</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Can anyone see why it's not working in Chrome?

Comment: Can you provide a link or something where we can reproduce your problem in the screenshot? Otherwise, it's impossible to find the root cause. BTW, you need to remove the fixed `width: 960px;` to make it more responsive.

Comment: In your code snippet, the stylesheet `Assets/stylesheets/main.css` cannot be loaded as it is a relative path.

Comment: @shaochuancs do you know a way I share the file here? it's a small folder

Comment: You can extract related CSS code in `main.css` and put them with your current snippet. It's not necessary to attach all your code here. Actually, a minified, complete and verifiable example will make us easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry @shaochuancs I didn't understand what you meant, all my related CSS is above, can you not see it?

Comment: Nvm found the answer, my files were in the wrong spot smh. But i do wonder, I was saving a different file path than I had originally? I wonder why that was

Answer (score 0):

Try using the

## Rysh

or

Rysh

or

Rysh